# Multiclass classification and unbalanced dataset

Tags: classification, svm, libsvm

I have a five-class SVM multiclass problem. The dataset is small (about 160 examples) and unbalanced i.e. I have classes with few examples. So far I further limited the dataset to 110 examples in order to work with a balanced training set... Is this a correct approach? Or should I work with an unbalanced training set? What are the advantages in this latter case? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

reducing a small set is a bad idea. keep all samples. if the classes are separable everything is fine. if not you can use the 'weight' feature to boost classes with little representation.